# Generic Default argument value of type cannot be converted

Tags: swift, generics

I have a simple `ParserType`, a PAT looking like this:

```
public protocol ParserType {
    associatedtype ModelType
    func parse(_ data: Any?) throws -> ModelType
}
```

I have a `WebService`:

```
public class WebService<ModelType, Parser: ParserType> {

    public typealias ModelType = Parser.ModelType
    private let parser: Parser
    ...

    public init(transport: ServiceTransport, endpoint: String, parser: Parser) {
        self.transport = transport
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.parser = parser
    }

    func fetch(...) -> ModelType {
        ...
        let result: ModelType = try! self.parser.parse(data)
        return result
    }
}
```

And a simple parser:

```
public class SimpleJSONParser<T: Codable>: ParserType {

    public typealias ModelType = T
    private let jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder

    public init(jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) {
        self.jsonDecoder = jsonDecoder
    }

    open func parse(_ data: Any?) throws -> T {
        let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: data as! Data)
        return response
    }
}
```

This works as expected.

However when I want to add a WebService subclass with a default parser, i.e.

```
class SimpleWebService<T: Codable, Parser: ParserType> : WebService<T, Parser> {

    override init(transport: ServiceTransport, endpoint: String, parser: Parser = SimpleJSONParser<T>()) {
        super.init(transport: transport, endpoint: endpoint, parser: parser)
    }
}
```

I get the following error:
`Default argument value of type 'SimpleJSONParser<T>' cannot be converted to type 'Parser'`. I would think `SimpleJSONParser` adheres to `ParserType`, but the compiler seems to think otherwise. Why is that?

Comment: Say I had a `class XMLParser : ParserType`; if your code were legal, the initialiser for `SimpleWebService<T, XMLParser>` would attempt to pass a `SimpleJSONParser` argument to an `XMLParser` parameter. `SimpleJSONParser` being a subtype of `ParserType` doesn't mean that it's a subtype of a generic placeholder constrained to `ParserType`. The placeholder can be satisfied by an *arbitrary* concrete type that conforms to `ParserType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By leaving the Parser generic, a `SimpleWebServer` may be instantiated with a parser type other than `SimpleJSONParser` (e.g. `let service = SimpleWebService<..., SimpleXMLParser>(...)` so you have a conflict between `SimpleJSONParser` and the generic type `Parser` which would be specialized to `SimpleXMLParser`.

So you would have to use a generic same-type constraint in an extension to add your initializer with a default value:

```
extension SimpleWebService where Parser == SimpleJSONParser<T> {
    convenience init(transport: ServiceTransport, endpoint: String, parser: Parser = SimpleJSONParser<T>()) {
        super.init(transport: transport, endpoint: endpoint, parser: parser)
    }
}
```

Note however that this code would not compile as it is currently not allowed to override a method in an extension.